# dataviz: How to set lineWidth property for chart

Tags: html, kendo-ui, data-visualization, kendo-dataviz, keen-io

I am using `dataviz` lib. for creating chart using `Keen-io`.
The chartType I am using is `line` and `spline` when I used

`.chartOptions({ curveType: "function",
        lineWidth: 10 })`

I am not able to see the line width change.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be great to see a jsfiddle or something showing your issue. I just created a fiddle using `chartOptions` and `lineWidth`, and it seems to be working swimmingly for me.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aqbtrxa8/11/

Code:

```
client.draw(query, el, {
    chartType: "linechart",
    height: 400,
    chartOptions: {
        lineWidth: 10
    }
});
```